# Generate BackSpace event gtk/C

Tags: c, gtk

In GTK/C, I want to propagate the `backspace` keypress to a `button` clicked. Following the suggestion in this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63258365/simulate-backspace-button-press-gtk-in-c), I tried with a small program: create an [GdkEventKey](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/unstable/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventKey) then use `gtk_propagate_event` to set the keypress to button. The program compiles normally but it did not function as I expected. I have found [this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2007-June/msg00115.html?fbclid=IwAR2cziw4Be6S5pyzmsB1emqAHUF2S8b6a9IElq1fYyU4zGVjOBH5Rhk2tZw), [this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2004-July/msg00036.html?fbclid=IwAR2FnBFLVnf1CUXhzExFlqLFChYsedQ6AVYVT9Jtp8q3zO8vym9p5uXWz8Q) and [this](https://directfb-dev.directfb.narkive.com/iCSH3JMv/question-about-gdk-event-put-for-keypress-event) but I couldn't get my code to work (when I click the `btn_bspace`, I want it to generate a backspace event in the `text_entry`). Could you look at my code and tell me what is wrong? Thank you very much!

```
//compile with gcc -o main main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>

GtkWidget *btn_bspace;
GtkWidget *entry;
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *box;

gboolean on_btn_bspace_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer data)
{
    guint keyval = GDK_KEY_BackSpace;
    
    GdkEvent* event = gdk_event_new(GDK_KEY_PRESS);
    ((GdkEventKey*)event)->window = gtk_widget_get_window(GTK_WIDGET(window));
    ((GdkEventKey*)event)->send_event = TRUE;
    ((GdkEventKey*)event)->time = GDK_CURRENT_TIME;
    ((GdkEventKey*)event)->state = GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK;
    ((GdkEventKey*)event)->keyval = keyval;
    ((GdkEventKey*)event)->state = 0;
    ((GdkEventKey*)event)->length = 0;
    ((GdkEventKey*)event)->string = 0;
    ((GdkEventKey*)event)->hardware_keycode = 0xff08;
    ((GdkEventKey*)event)->group = 0;
    gtk_propagate_event(entry, event);
    return FALSE;
    }
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
   
    box = gtk_box_new(FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);
    gtk_widget_show(box);
    
    entry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry), "testing");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), entry, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show(entry);
    
    btn_bspace = gtk_button_new_with_label("Backspace");
    g_signal_connect(btn_bspace, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_btn_bspace_clicked), NULL);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), btn_bspace, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show(btn_bspace);
    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

**Update**: assign `((GdkEventKey)event)->window` to a `GdkWindow`

Comment: Have you stepped through in debug mode to see if you can detect unexpected values?  Also, mention what OS you are using in your post somewhere.

Comment: I am writing app in raspbian buster (debian 10), I used gdb as you suggested but couldn't find any problem. I updated the full code, could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is still a relevant issue for you, but I did some investigation into this issue to come up with a solution.  Perhaps you or others can benefit from the information.

I tested out your code and was also getting no response to the button click event.  In researching this, what seems to be the issue is that trying to match up a GtkWindow to a GdkWindow seems to falter.  I am not proficient in how to get GTK objects to communicate with GDK objects.  So, I looked at a different approach that just relied on GTK objects and events.

I took a look at the source code for the GtkEntry widget to see what type of signals it accepts and went at this with a different approach.  Instead of utilizing a GDK event, I emitted a signal to the entry widget for a backspace.  Backspace is one of the signals associated with a GtkEntry widget.

[image: GTK Entry backspace signal]

The "on_btn_bspace_clicked" function was revised as follows:

```
void on_btn_bspace_clicked(GtkEntry *ent, gpointer data)
{
    g_signal_emit (ent, g_signal_lookup ("backspace", G_OBJECT_CLASS_TYPE (GTK_WIDGET_GET_CLASS(GTK_ENTRY(ent)))), 0);
}
```

This actually simplified the code a bit.

Then within your mainline block, I revised the signal connection to utilize the "g_signal_connect_swapped" function which lets one reference the widget to be affected.

```
g_signal_connect_swapped(btn_bspace, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_btn_bspace_clicked), entry);
```

I tested this revision out and got the result that you were after.

[image: Backspace button illustration]

I hope this helps you out.

Regards.